# Disable markdown for a block

Tags: html, markdown

Markdown syntax is convenient to write blogs and comments but at times it interferes when you want to write HTML. Is there a tag / syntax to ignore that part like the `pre` HTML tag? If `pre` works, what if the markdown part needs to include an HTML tag?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The original implementation of Markdown (by Gruber) and PHP Markdown don't format inside block-level HTML elements, so you can use `<div>`, for example:

```
Markdown text.

More markdown text.

<div>
Markdown ignores inside the div, you can do all sorts of crazy stuff:
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>.
<blink>Is blink still supported?</blink>
</div>

Yet more markdown text.
```

Will get rendered as:

```
<p>Markdown text.</p>

<p>More markdown text.</p>

<div>
Markdown ignores inside the div, you can do all sorts of crazy stuff:
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>.
<blink>Is blink still supported?</blink>
</div>

<p>Yet more markdown text.</p>
```

Comment: Which implementation are you using?

Comment: Tested with both Markdown.pl and PHP Markdown, btw.

Comment: Yup, Actually works. Thanks! doesnt perhaps work when the <div> is enclosed within a <code>

Answer (score 12):

At least here on Stack Overflow, the ... `<pre>` HTML tag works just fine for that purpose. It also formats your text like a browser would:

```
This is pre-formatted, so in here I can /slash/ and *star* stuff
without issues, and [[square brackets]] [are] just brackets.
```

Comment: Also, use backticsk (`) for shorter snippets inside larger formatted areas.